# How to match "=" not inside a pair of brackets by regex?

Tags: regex

How to use regex to match "=" not inside a pair of brackets by regex?

Valid: a **=** b

Valid (the second equal sign): {1=1} a **=** b {2=2}

Invalid: {a = b}

Invalid: {{1=1} a = b}

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please specify what specific variant/flavor of regular expressions you're using, describe what research you've done, show your best attempts, etc.

Comment: In the general case, you can't do this with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it. That's because it requires keeping track of how many left and right brackets there are, and you can't do that in regular languages.

The "regular" in "regular expressions" is the same as the "regular" in "regular languages". However, keeping track can be done in context-free languages, which are expressed through grammars instead of regex.